# Assign a number of occurrence to each record (sort of Count if)

Tags: excel, count, powerquery, countif

How can I achieve the same calculation in Power Query?

In Excel I would use: `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)`

```
Name    Occurrence
A          1
A          2
B          1
A          3
B          2
```

Thanks,
Tamir

Answer (score 2):

This could be reached via "buttons" only (almost - except some custom column formula):

```
AddedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
GroupedRows = Table.Group(AddedIndex, {"Name"}, {{"tmp", each _, type table}}),
AddedCustom = Table.AddColumn(GroupedRows, "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([tmp],"Occurrence", 1,1)),
RemovedOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(AddedCustom,{"Custom"}),
Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(RemovedOtherColumns, "Custom", {"Name", "Occurrence"}, {"Name", "Occurrence"})
```

Or, shorter:

```
AddedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
GroupedRows = Table.Group(AddedIndex, {"Name"}, {{"tmp", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Occurence", 1,1), type table}}),
Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GroupedRows, "tmp", {"Occurrence"}, {"Occurrence"})
```

There you can also extract `Index` column and sort by it, if you need to preserve initial row order. Also all other necessary columns have to be extracted on the last step

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a running count is definitely possible in PQ, though one of those things that is not super simple due to how PQ is designed to look at data. There is probably a more efficient way, but this is what I came up with.

First add an Index column that starts at 1, so we can easily track the "row" we are on. Then add a custom column with this in it

```
Number.Abs(List.Count(List.RemoveItems(List.Range(#"Added Index"[Name], 0, [Index]), {[Name]}))-List.Count(List.Range(#"Added Index"[Name], 0, [Index])))
```

I didn't see a simple list function in PQ that counts matching items in a list, so instead we get the count of items in a list by taking the difference in count between a list with the matching items *removed* and the base count of the list. The index is used to so we can check against a list only up to our current "row" by using List.Range.

The full M code when I pulled in a table of sample data looked like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Occurence", each Number.Abs(List.Count(List.RemoveItems(List.Range(#"Added Index"[Name], 0, [Index]), {[Name]}))-List.Count(List.Range(#"Added Index"[Name], 0, [Index]))))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```